# Как обойти уровень конфиденциальности excel через win32com python

Tags: python, excel

Помогите в вопросе:
Собрал скрипт, который автообновляет excel файл через библиотеку win32com.client.
Использую скрипт на работе, где запрашивается допуск к файлам.
Скрипт работает, но ломается, когда слетает конфиденциальность (бесконечно грузит, пытается обновить файл).
Можно ли как-то обойти этот пункт или автоматически подтверждать?
[image: уровни конфиденциальности]

```
try:
    xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    if password=='':
        wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(path, 2, False, None, None)
    else:
        wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(path, 2, False, None, None, '30', True)
    try:
        wb.RefreshAll()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False 
        wb.Save()
        print('файл',file,'обновился')
    except:
        wb.SaveAs("C:\\Ошибки при автообновлении\\"+file)
        print('не обновился  файл '+file+', но сохранен')
    finally:
        wb.Close()
except:
    print('не обновился файл',file)
finally:
    xlapp.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят, оказывается не до конца протестировал, при запросе уровня конфиденциальности этот скрипт обновляет вхолостую файл, не тормозя при этом весь процесс и обновление последующих файлов, это и нужно было.